# Prove by cases that $|x|≤R \iff -R≤x≤R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Prove by cases that:

$$|x|≤R \iff -R≤x≤R$$

$R$ is defined as $R≥0$.

I consider the two relevant cases to be $x≥0$ and $x<0$. However, for the latter, if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$. This yields $-x≤R \iff x≥-R$. Moreover, we have $0>x≥-R$, which implies that $0>-R \iff 0<R$. Thus we end up with $R>0>x≥-R$, or, if turned around and omitting the zero, $-R≤x<R$.

I don't see how this expression is equivalent to the above. According to my book the equivalence should hold for $x≥0$ and $x<0$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Let's distinguish 2 cases.

1. Let $x \geq 0$. Then, $|x|\leq R$ means that $x \leq R$. Moreover, $0\leq x \leq R$. Since $R\geq 0$, $-R\leq 0$. Then, $-R\leq 0 \leq x \leq R$. That is $-R\leq x \leq R$.
2. Let $x <0$. Then $|x|\leq R$ means that $-x \leq R$. I.e. $-R\leq x$. Since $R\geq 0$, $0\leq R$. Then, $-R\leq x< 0 \leq R$. That is $-R\leq x\leq R$.

Comment: How do you conclude that if $-x \leq R$ and $-R \leq x$ implies $-R \leq x \leq R$? How can we know that $x \leq R$?

Comment: I have edited it. Maybe now is more clear. @user37043

Comment: In your second case, how do you justify $-R\leq x\leq 0 \leq R$ if $x<0$. Shouldn't it be $-R\leq x < 0 \leq R$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But anyway, $-R\leq x <0 \leq R$ implies $-R\leq x \leq R$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: If $<0$ and $0 \leq R$, isn't $R$ incorrectly defined then? For which number can $x=R$?

Comment: How about the opposite side? You only proved $|x| \le R \Rightarrow -R \le x \le R.$

Comment: I think that $R>0$. Because if $R=0$, $x$ must be zero. And you have finished.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if $x < 0$ then $x \ne R$ and those we have $-R \le x < 0$.  This is a subcase of $-R \le x \le -R$ but we do have that $0\le x \le R$ are all not possible in this case where $x< 0$.

But that is not a problem.  Those cases become possible if $x \ge 0$.  If $x \ge 0$ then $0 \le x \le -R$ and this is a subcase of $-R \le x \le R$ but we have now have that $-R \le x < 0$ is impossible.

I think you are confusing "Prove by cases $X \iff Y$ with

Prove $Case 1 \iff Y$ and $Case 2 \iff Y$.

That is *not* what we have to prove.  (In fact that is impossible as that would mean $Case 1 \iff Case 2$ which is oviously not the case).

To prove it by cases actually means prove

$Case 1 \implies Y$

$Case 2 \implies Y$ and $Y \implies Case 1$ or $Case 2$.

In this case:

Case 1: $x < 0$ and $|x| \le R$; then $-R \le x < 0$ so $-R \le x \le R$.

Case 2: $x \ge 0$ and $|x| \le R$; then $0 \le x < R$ so $-R \le x \le R$.

And if $-R \le x \le R$ then either $0 \le x \le R$ and $|x| \le R$ or $-R \le x < 0$ and $|x| \le R$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. In your Case 1, how do you justify $-R \le x < 0 \implies -R \le x \le R$?

Comment: Because if $x < 0$ and $R \ge 0$ then $x \le R$.  An inequality is an *IN*equality.  If $a < b$ then $a <$ everything bigger than $b$.  Oh and a "less then or equal to" is a less than *OR* equal to.  So if $a < b$ then $a \le b$ because if $a$ is less than $b$ then $a$ is less than $b$ or $a = b$.  It is true that I am an earthling or I am from Alpha Centauri because.... I am an earthling.

Comment: Can you justive that if $x \in [-R, 0)$ then $x\in [-R, R]$ because $[-R,0) \subset [-R,R]$.  I think you are tripping up when we say something *might* be true you are confusing it with there has to be some cases where it *is* true.  I am a human being.  Therefore I am a mammal.  $x < 0$ therefore $x \le R$.  Saying I am a mammal doesn't mean it's possible that I am a non-human animal.  And saying $x \le R$ doesn't mean it's possible that $0 \le x \le R$.

Comment: Put another way.  For $-R \le x \le R$ to be *false* we must have $x > R$ which is not possible because $x < 0$.  Or we must have $x < -R$ which is not possible because $-R\le x$.  So it is not *false* that $-R \le x \le R$.  So it most be true.

Comment: Also $-R \le x \le R$ means $x$ is in the range of $-R$ to $R$.  So if $-R \le x < 0$ ***is*** $x$ in the range of $-R$ to $R$?  Well..... um... yes?

Comment: So $a<b \implies a \le b$? Also, in your answer, first paragraph, second sentence. Is $-R \le x \le -R$ a typo? Do you mean $-R \le x \le R$? And second paragraph, third sentence. Do you mean $0 \le x \le R$ instead of $0 \le x \le -R$?

Comment: OF COURSE $a < b \implies a \le b$!  If $a$ is less then $b$ then $a < b$ or $a = b$.   Like I said.  I am an earthling implies I am an earthling or I am from alpha centauri.  After all, it *is* true I am from one of the planets Earth or Alpha Centauri.  And I'm not from Alpha Centauri.

Comment: Why is $a < b \implies a\le b$ a hard concept for you?

Comment: $a < b$ means $a$ is in the range $-\infty$ upto but not including $b$.  $a \le b$ means $a is in the range $-\infty$ upto maybe including $b$.  If $a$ is in the range $-\infty$ up to but not including $b$ does that mean $a$ is in the range $-\infty$ upto and maybe including $b$?  Well..... yes.  $a$ certainly isn't *OUT* of that range.

Comment: I think the concept is growing on me. Thanks for taking the time. Are the 'typos' I pointed out in my earlier comment typos?

Comment: I‘d appreciate the correction of any typo, since they leave me doubtful!